# Create a generic method with generic signature

Tags: java, spring-boot

i have some redundant code that i would like to remove, my goal would be to create a method of this kind:

```
private GenericClass myMethod(GenericClass genericClass){
    genericClass.getTipe(); //tipe1 or tipe2
    genericClass.setValue("foo");
    genericClass.setValue2("foo");
    //some logic
    return genericClass;

}
```

Where this method can pass two similar classes but which differ in the type of an attribute

```
public class Class1{
   private Tipe1 tipe1;
   private String value; 
   private String value2;
   //Constructor,Getter and Setter
}

public class Class2{
   private Tipe2 tipe2;
   private String value; 
   private String value2;
   //Constructor,Getter and Setter
}
```

What I would like to do is call the method

> someServiceIml.myMethod ("Foo")

passing either an object of type `Class1` or `Class2` according to my needs, the business logic behind `myMethod` is practically the same.

This method i wish it was in the same implementation of a certain service, could you give me some solution?

Comment: Use a common base class?

Comment: Can you give me a toy example?

Comment: It's hard to give a concrete answer without a concrete question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a generic abstract type; either a super class or an interface:

```
public interface GenericClass<T> {
    public T getTipe();
    public void setValue(String s);
    public void setValue2(String s);
}
```

Have your implementation classes implement it:

```
public class Class1 implements GenericClass<Tipe1> {
    // leave implementation as is
}

public class Class2 implements GenericClass<Tipe2> {
    // leave implementation as is
}
```

And type your method:

```
private <T> GenericClass<T> myMethod(GenericClass<T> genericClass){
    T tipe = genericClass.getTipe();
    genericClass.setValue("foo");
    genericClass.setValue2("foo");
    // some logic
    return genericClass;
}
```

If `Tipe1` and `Tipe2` share a common type, you can type them too:

```
public interface GenericClass<T extends SomeTipe> {
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      
        Class1 c1 = new Class1();
        
        Class2 c2 = new Class2();

        GenericClass gc = myMethod(c1);
        
        System.out.println(gc);
    }
    
    private static GenericClass myMethod(GenericClass genericClass){
        genericClass.getTipe(); //tipe1 or tipe2
        genericClass.setValue("foo");
        genericClass.setValue2("foo");
        //some logic
        return genericClass;
    }
}

class Class1 extends GenericClass<Tipe1>{

}

class Class2 extends GenericClass<Tipe2>{

}

class Tipe1 {
    
}
class Tipe2 {
    
}

class GenericClass<T> implements Tipe<T> {
    private String value;
    private String value2;
    private T t;
    
    public T getTipe() {
        return t;
    }
    
    void setValue(String s) {
        value = s;
    }
    void setValue2(String s) {
        value2 = s;
    }
}

interface Tipe<T> {
    public T getTipe();
}
```

or you can cast to parent class like:

```
GenericClass gc = new Class2();
```